# How can I extract the content between two brackets?

Tags: regex, shell, unix

My input:

```
   1:FAILED      +  *1      0     (8328832,AR,UNDECLARED)
```

This is what I expect:

```
8328832,AR,UNDECLARED
```

I am trying to find a general regular expression that allows to take any content between two brackets out.

My attempt is

```
  grep -o '\[(.*?)\]' test.txt > output.txt
```

but it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Still using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)**

```
grep -oP '\(\K[^\)]+' file
```

`\K` means that use *look around* regex advanced feature. More precisely, it's a *positive look-behind assertion*, you can do it like this too :

```
grep -oP '(?<=\()[^\)]+' file
```

if you lack the `-P` option, you can do this with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lne '/\(\K[^\)]+/ and print $&' file
```

**Another simpler approach using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)**

```
awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' file
```

Comment: I got "grep:parentheses not balanced" after I ran this.Is the letter P a typo? @sputnick

Comment: Which OS do you use and wich grep ?

Comment: is OS X(UNIX) @sputnick

Comment: Can you explain the "simple" approach using `awk`?

Comment: @ tommy.carstensen  The -F flag sets a pattern as the field delimiter, where the pattern being used is a regex character class for either '(' or ')'.  It looks for either character on the line and returns everything after it (the $2nd field), up until the next field delimiter, whether it be '(' or ')'.  For this solution to work as intended, it assumes that there is only one parenthetical group or that you only want to select text within the first group, plus it assumes that the "close" paren ')' will not precede the "open" paren '(' on a line', else your fields will be shifted